# infinispan exception during wildfly app server startup

Tags: jboss, wildfly, infinispan, jgroups

I am getting the following error in Wildfly server logs when ear application is deployed in wildfly (version 8.2) app server. The application is running in a clustered setup with 6 nodes in the cluster.

Any idea when this exception is thrown?

```
2016-10-26 17:57:56,606 ERROR [OOB-18,shared=udp]-[org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl] ISPN000260: Exception executing command: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.cache.infinispan.util.EvictAllCommand.perform(EvictAllCommand.java:64)
at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleInternal(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:95)
at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handleWithWaitForBlocks(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:186)
at org.infinispan.remoting.InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.handle(InboundInvocationHandlerImpl.java:84)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.executeCommandFromLocalCluster(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:259)
at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.handle(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:211)
at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.handleRequest(RequestCorrelator.java:460)
at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receiveMessage(RequestCorrelator.java:377)
at org.jgroups.blocks.RequestCorrelator.receive(RequestCorrelator.java:247)
at org.jgroups.blocks.MessageDispatcher$ProtocolAdapter.up(MessageDispatcher.java:667)
at org.jgroups.blocks.mux.MuxUpHandler.up(MuxUpHandler.java:130)
at org.jgroups.JChannel.up(JChannel.java:708)
at org.jgroups.stack.ProtocolStack.up(ProtocolStack.java:1015)
at org.jgroups.protocols.RSVP.up(RSVP.java:187)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FRAG2.up(FRAG2.java:165)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.GMS.up(GMS.java:1010)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.STABLE.up(STABLE.java:234)
at org.jgroups.protocols.UNICAST3.up(UNICAST3.java:391)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.handleMessage(NAKACK2.java:774)
at org.jgroups.protocols.pbcast.NAKACK2.up(NAKACK2.java:570)
at org.jgroups.protocols.VERIFY_SUSPECT.up(VERIFY_SUSPECT.java:147)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_ALL.up(FD_ALL.java:185)
at org.jgroups.protocols.FD_SOCK.up(FD_SOCK.java:301)
at org.jgroups.protocols.MERGE3.up(MERGE3.java:303)
at org.jgroups.protocols.Discovery.up(Discovery.java:379)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$ProtocolAdapter.up(TP.java:2641)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP.passMessageUp(TP.java:1429)
at org.jgroups.protocols.TP$MyHandler.run(TP.java:1615)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This seems like race condition; the application on one node is calling `evictAll()` before the other node (throwing the exception) fully starts up and initializes the region.

Comment: I also suspected the same. This happened only once.. never occurred even after multiple restarts. Is there a way to avoid such conditions??

Comment: Not really, this is a bug and should be handled in ORM (I think it applies to version 5.x as well). Please file an issue in issue tracker.

Comment: Filed a bug in the infinispan component. https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ISPN-7164. Please feel free to add your comments.

Comment: This is actually a bug in ORM module, so the bug should go into Hibernate tracker https://hibernate.atlassian.net/

Comment: Created ticket in Hibernate forum https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11226